# In SwiftUI how do I decrease the size or get rid of a Section header when using InsetGroupedListStyle?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

In a view like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Section("How do I get rid of this space") {
        Text("Static content")
      }
      
      Section("How do I get rid of this space") {
        Text("Static content")
      }
      
      Section("How do I get rid of this space") {
        Text("Dynamic content")
        Text("Dynamic content")
        Text("Dynamic content")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that looks like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of the space where the Section header is (marked with `How do I get rid of this space`)? I'm putting some static navigation links in that space and I prefer the insetGrouped ListStyle.

I've tried dabbling with UIKit:

```
UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

but it doesnt get rid of the full height and applies globally. I'd like to use it only for this one list. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154356/12299030?

Comment: That one did not work but the answer below did the trick. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73174782/4269720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 1)` and             `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -20, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))` worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can control header footer heights using `listRowInsets`, you can modify all insets according to your requirements.

[image]